# Why do I still need two different solution (*.sln) files for Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I see a lot of projects around with to solution files, one for Visual Studio, one for Xamarin Studio.
Today I have created a solution in Visual Studio 2012 that contains one PCL and one iOS project. 
If I open that solution in Xamarin Studio, I have many build combinations but none of them will build both, the PCL and the iOS solution:

[image]

If however I create a new empty solution for XS and add the projects from the VS solution, it works. Why are the build configurations handled differently? I thought, solution files would be standardized and interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio and Xamarin studio .sln are compatible and interchangeable. However **they are not standardized**. If you open .sln with one and another, the XML will not look the same.

But really, it is just the XML that is modified in different ways. XS will add a lot of marker tags and additional configuration that VS does not need. In the end, it will still be readable by both IDE.

The other major difference seems to be between the Xamarin VS plugin and XS. I also noticed that one or another doesn't have all the option for creating project or even for building configuration.

For instance, when I need to create an Android.UnitTest project using NUnitLite, Xamarin VS plugin don't allow me to create this type of project inside VS. I have to create it in XS first and use VS to import it after.